# to_sql works up to 300k rows above it gives error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, odbc

I want to send a dataframe to ms sql with the to_sql pandas function. However if i limited the dataframe to 300k rows it works above that it gives this error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect.

same happens when chunksize is increased

what will solve this problem?

This is the code:

```
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server\SQLEXPRESS01;DATABASE=test") #server and database name are left out
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted),use_setinputsizes=False)

test.to_sql('Table_2', schema='dbo', chunksize=5, con = engine, method='multi', index=False, if_exists='replace') #
```

Comment: Try changing to a the newer ODBC driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16